# Setting grub2 boot options for RHEL7 installer with virt-install

Tags: system-installation, grub2, virtual-machine, kvm

Per RHEL documentation it is possible to [edit the grub2 prior to launching the installer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options.html), in case special options are needed ahead of time.  The same holds true for CentOS.

When I point virt-install to a local ISO image, by the time I can launch a remote virt-manager instance, the installer proceeded past the option to set grub2 options (there is a several second delay).

Is there any way to pass grub2 options to the installer using virt-install?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible, however I needed to have my remote `virt-manager` instance up and already connected to the host.

As soon as the `virt-install` command is issued at the host, I see the new guest instance appear in `virt-manager`, and was able to connect to it in time to edit configuration options for the installer.